# iOS application crashes occasionally if mapview is entered straight after opening the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I have created an iPhone Application running version 6.1.
In one of my views i am using a mapview including annotation pin, zoom to location.

The app runs fine if all of the other views has been opened first and the mapview dont crash.
However, if i open the app and go straigt to the mapview viewcontroller the app crashes??

Furthermore the app only crashes on my iPhone 4S device, and NOT in the controler???

Can anyone help me please??

Best regards.

Here is my code for the mapview:

```
    @interface VisPaaKortViewController ()

@end

@implementation VisPaaKortViewController
@synthesize mapView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;




    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    // Create a view of the standard size at the top of the screen.
    // Available AdSize constants are explained in GADAdSize.h.
    bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];

    // Specify the ad's "unit identifier". This is your AdMob Publisher ID.
    bannerView_.adUnitID = @"my_publisher_id";

    // Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
    // the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
    bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];


    //Placement of banner
    [bannerView_ setFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                     362,
                                     bannerView_.bounds.size.width,
                                     bannerView_.bounds.size.height)];



    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];


}


-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self performSelector:@selector(zoomInToMyLocation)
               withObject:nil
               afterDelay:0];
}





- (void)zoomInToMyLocation
{


    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = (double) 59.778747;
    location.longitude = (double) 9.292349;



    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, 800, 800);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:NO];


    // Add an annotation
    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point.coordinate = location;
    point.title = @"Text";
    point.subtitle = @"Text";

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
    [self.mapView selectAnnotation:[[self.mapView annotations] objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: Show what the error is when it crashes. Most of the time, it contains the answer.

Comment: This is the error i get:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region <center:nan, nan span:nan, nan>'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x344fb2a3 0x3c22397f 0x344faf99 0x353283c9 0x353284e7 0x3532651d 0x35311e83 0x35311db7 0x353249e1 0x364e8ac7 0x363666bf 0x344f6aef 0x344efa79 0x34451b6b 0x3631f0ab 0x36740c2d 0x3630ca91 0x36306803 0x360b0d8b 0x360b0929 0x360b185d 0x360b1243 0x360b1051 0x360b0eb1 0x344d06cd 0x344ce9c1 0x344ced17 0x34441ebd 0x34441d49 0x3801a2eb 0x36357301 0xf3be5 0x3c65ab20)
libc++abi.dylib: 
(lldb)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't provide much detail I have to guess. I assume that you use ARC, and I would try to add `self.mapView.delegate = nil;` to your dealloc method.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    self.mapView.delegate = nil;
}
```

`MKMapView`s delegate is declared `assign` and not `weak`, which means it's possible that the delegate can still be referenced when the viewController is already deallocated.

And if you don't use ARC you should still nil the mapView.delegate in your dealloc.

Comment: This is the error i get: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region <center:nan, nan span:nan, nan>'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x344fb2a3 0x3c22397f 0x344faf99 0x353283c9 0x353284e7 0x3532651d 0x35311e83 0x35311db7 0x353249e1 0x364e8ac7 0x363666bf 0x344f6aef 0x344efa79 0x34451b6b 0x3631f0ab 0x36740c2d 0x3630ca91 0x36306803 0x360b0d8b 0x360b0929 0x360b185d 0x360b1243 0x360b1051 0x360b0eb1 0x344d06cd 0x344ce9c1 0x344ced17 0x34441ebd 0x34441d49 0x3801a2eb 0x36357301 0xf3be5 0x3c65ab20)
libc++abi.dylib: 
(lldb)